# Array copy show 0 1 instead true false in Swift

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift

I have made an Array:

```
var hugett = [[[true, false], [true, true], [true, true, true], [true, true, false, false], [false]],[]]
```

And made a copy of the first index in the array:

```
tempott = hugett[0]
```

BUT! when I print it I get different results, when I print the original array (`hugett`):

```
[[true, false], [true, true], [true, true, true], [true, true, false, false], [false]]
```

And when I print the copy (`tempott`), this is what I get:

```
((
        (
        1,
        0
    ),
        (
        1,
        1
    ),
        (
        1,
        1,
        1
    ),
        (
        1,
        1,
        0,
        0
    ),
        (
        0
    )
))
```

Instead of showing me true/false - What is my mistake making it 0/1?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using `NSLog("%@", tempott)` to print the array, that's why it's bridged to Objective-C and you get this instead of "true" and "false".

Just print it with Swift's `print` and you'll see the Bool values: `print(tempott)`.

There's also `dump(tempott)` which can be useful to inspect the object.

*Update after your comment:*

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: I print it with print:
print(tempott).

But the problem is not in the print, the problem is that I need to use the tempott with the true and false and I cant because of the 0/1.

Comment: `I print it with print: print(tempott)` Sorry but when printed with `print` I get true and false, not 0 and 1. I can't reproduce your issue in a Playground. You must be confused about something, please check your code.

Comment: How did you create your tempott?

Comment: First of all thank you for your help. I have found the issue: I have created the tempott outside the class as an NSArray and not as [Array<Bool>](), but I fixed it :)

Comment: Ah, right, I should have thought about this possibility. ;) It's nice that you fixed your issue anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I created the array as:

```
var tempott: NSArray
```

instead of:

```
var tempott = [Array<Bool>]()
```